# Trying to display created output file

Tags: java, printwriter

So i passed a file into filewriter and then passed to printwriter. However, upon my assignments instructions im supposed to print these variables i pass to printwriter using a toString method in my superclass. This is for an assignment so thats why the rules are very clear as to how instructors wants the output to be.

```
 System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");
    fileName = input.next();
    File fw = new File(fileName + ".txt");       

 AccountWithException acctException = new AccountWithException(fullName, balance, id, RATE);

 System.out.println(acctException.toString()); <---This works


 // pass object to printwriter and pw to write to the file
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        // print to created file
        pw.println(firstName);
        pw.println(lastName);
        pw.println(balance);
        pw.println(id);
        pw.println(RATE);
        System.out.println(pw.toString());  <---Doesn't work. Only prints location and im supposed to somehow use the overloaded toString method to output the data within the file (i guess after its written)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually given your own solution, but you need something like this -

```
pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
try {
  // print to created file
  // pw.println(firstName);
  // pw.println(lastName);
  // pw.println(balance);
  // pw.println(id);
  // pw.println(RATE);
  pw.println(acctException.toString()); // <-- Since 
                    // System.out.println(acctException.toString()); works!
} finally {
  pw.close(); // <-- Always close()!
}
```

Comment: Well no one is supposed to be printing my account object as toString and the other output should be of the output file ive created.

Comment: @javaaaaaa "I'm supposed to print these variables i pass to printwriter using a toString method"; if it's in a super-class somehow then call `super.toString(pw);` or similar.

Comment: Vote my post up if ud like elliot. I literally spent half and hour trying to tinker with this!